# Jquery Datepicker add 2 years to year not based on month/day

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have implemented the jQuery datepicker to allow the selection of dates on a form, it should allow the selection of date based on the current date + 2 years  however in the final year it will not proceed past the current date or month.

As such if today is 15/03/2012 the maximum available date would be 15/03/14. However, I require the entire of 2014 to be selectable. As such, the maximum should be 31/12/14.

How would I best go about this to enable it to auto update as it currently does?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- 
         $(function() {
           $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 3,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                defaultDate: "+1w",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                numberOfMonths: 3,
                minDate: "-0",
                maxDate: "2y",
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
    });
    -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `yearRange` options. Use it like

```
yearRange: 'c:c+2'
```

Here, `c` represnts current year and `c+2` the next two years.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    yearRange: 'c:c+2',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/Gw3Lz/) for the above example.

Comment: your solution allows date selection beyond 2014 which OP wants not allowed. Just go to 2014 and select Dec and the picker will allow selection of dates in 2015.

Comment: @bPratik, I think op wants to show two extra year when a data is selected.

Comment: Quoting OP: _"based on the current date + 2 years however in the final year it will not proceed past the current date or month. As such if today is 15/03/2012 the maximum available date would be 15/03/14"_ *Means that Max year selectable should be 2014.* Continuing on: _"However, I require the entire of 2014 to be selectable. As such, the maximum should be 31/12/14"_ *Means last date selectable should be 31/12 of 2014.* That's what it meant to me. :) Either way, between our answers all OP's possibilities have been covered!

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle should work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/z85pB/